# Using the new ES6 Array.from() method

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, typed-arrays

There's one aspect of the new `Array.from` method that I'm not understanding. I'm reading the through the [Description section on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Description), and came across the following:

> `Array.from()` has an optional parameter `mapFn`, which allows you to execute a map function on each element of the array (or subclass object) that is being created. More clearly, `Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array. This is especially important for certain array subclasses, like [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays), since the intermediate array would necessarily have values truncated to fit into the appropriate type.

I'm not understanding:

> ...the intermediate array would necessarily have values truncated to fit into the appropriate type

I'm not sure what this is saying, since we're going from a typed array to a normal `Array` (using `Array.from`). It's not like any incorrect types will be in the typed array. Also, the resulting `Array` from `Array.from()` will of course accept any type like normal JS arrays do.

Could anyone give insight into what this is trying to say or what I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array subclasses inherit the `from` method from `Array`, so you can e.g. call

```
const iter = (function*() { for (var i=0; i<512; i++) yield i }());
const arr = Uint8Array.from(iter);
console.log(arr); // Uint8Array(512) […, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, 2, 3, …]
```

The resulting array is an `Uint8Array` and has the values truncated respectively. If you provided a mapping function, it would have made a difference whether you used `Uint8Array.from(iter, fn)` or `Uint8Array.from(iter).map(fn)`.

Comment: Thank you @Bergi, that makes much more sense now. So `Uint8Array.from(...` returns an instance of `Uint8Array` because `from()` was called on the `Uint8Array` subclass, even though I believe the `from()` method is defined at the top level built-in `Array` class correct?

Comment: @qarthandso Yes, exactly